# How to add static properties to class using decorators in Typescript

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript-typings

I am trying to add some properties to a class using decorators. But I am getting Compile time errors.
I have my code structured somewhat like this.

```
type ModuleConfig = {
    ModuleName: string
    // ...other properties
}

type ModuleClass = {
    ModuleName: string
}

type TargetClass = {}

function Module(moduleConfig: ModuleConfig ): Function {
    return function(targetClass: TargetClass): ModuleClass {
        Object.defineProperty(targetClass,"ModuleName", { value: moduleConfig.ModuleName })

        // ...Define other properties in targetClass based on other properties of moduleConfig.

        return <ModuleClass>targetClass
    }
}

==================================

@Module({
    ModuleName: "App"
    // ...other properties
})
class AppModule {}

===================================


let Config = {
    RootModule: AppModule,
    modules:[
        // other Modules
    ]
}

===================================

type ModulesConfig = {
    RootModule: ModuleClass,
    modules?: Array<ModuleClass>
}

function RegisterModules(config: ModulesConfig): Function {
    return function(target: any, name: string,  descriptor: PropertyDescriptor): PropertyDescriptor {

        let origFn = descriptor.value

        let newFn = function() {
            let RootModule = config.RootModule.ModuleName

            let args: FinalConfig = {
                RootModule: RootModule,
                modules: {config.RootModule, ...config.modules}
            }

            origFn.call(target, args)
        }

        descriptor.value = newFn
        return descriptor
}

class ThatTakesCareofSomeCoreFunctionality {

    @RegisterModules(Config)
    intialize() {

    }
}
```

Quite a long problematic code, but I am getting following errors,
I am not able to find out what's wrong with my decorators or typings.

```
Argument of type '{ RootModule: typeof AppModule; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ModulesConfig'.
  Types of property 'RootModule' are incompatible.
    Type 'typeof AppModule' is not assignable to type 'ModuleClass'.
      Property 'ModuleName' is missing in type 'typeof AppModule'.
```

Am I missing something???

Comment: You are not missing anything, it's just that decorators are not considered when doing compile-time type-checking. It's a limitation.

Comment: Thanks, @JohnWeisz for answering. I have been waiting for such a long time.  So, how do I escape the error???

Comment: @besrabasant have any news on the possibility of static properties yet?